# Please why does this code refresh my page after the onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = function () {
        var songTitle = document.getElementById("songTextInput").value;
        if (songTitle == "") alert("Baba Put Something Jare");
        else {
            var playlist = document.getElementById("playlist");
            var song = document.createElement("li");
            song.innerHTML = songTitle;
            playlist.appendChild(song);
        }
    };
}
```

The HTML body consist of :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Web Tunes</title>
  <script src="playlist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" placeholder="Song Title">
    <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="Add Song">
  </form>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

The code outputs the new list element but refreshes immediately.. Please help.

Comment: use event.preventDefault(); so that it will stop the form to submit

Comment: Thanks Guys. Head First HTML Programming used this code and i guess it worked for them. No book is perfect after all.. Pls How do we inform them? For the sake of future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an **input type submit** inside a form tag. A submit button **posts** the form to the server. Just add `return false;` to stop the form from being posted to the server.

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = function () {
        var songTitle = document.getElementById("songTextInput").value;
        if (songTitle == "") alert("Baba Put Something Jare");
        else {
            var playlist = document.getElementById("playlist");
            var song = document.createElement("li");
            song.innerHTML = songTitle;
            playlist.appendChild(song);
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Web Tunes</title>
  <script src="playlist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" placeholder="Song Title">
    <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="Add Song">

  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

From above your js code, no need to use the ***form tag***.
Because we can get directly